# Getting index of a function from a List of function pointers

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

I have a list of functions, all of which extend the Consumer interface. I need to extract out the index of the functions. The reason for this is that I'm implementing a cyclic workflow, where a user invokes functions in the list sequentially. So, when a user finishes with foo, foo calls a scheduler function which schedules the function after foo in the list. For this, foo needs to be aware of its own index in the list. I don't wish to hard code numbers, which is why I'm trying to retrieve the index of foo. This is what I have:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Experiment {

  private List<Consumer<String>> activities = ImmutableList.of(
  this::bar,
  this::foo
  );

  public void bar(String x) {
    System.out.println();
  }

  public void foo(String x) {
    System.out.println();
  }

  public void print() {
    System.out.println(activities.indexOf((Consumer<String>)this::foo));
  }

  public static void main(String []args) {
    Experiment e = new Experiment();
    e.print();
  }
}
```

That prints `-1` for me, so it couldn't find it in the list. Is there a way of extracting out the index of a function from this list?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm implementing a cyclic workflow, where a user invokes functions sequentially.

Comment: That's not very clear to me. If they are invoking things sequentially, just iterate over `activities`.

Comment: Still doesn't explain why you need to know the index. There are all kinds of reasons that sounds like a bad design...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Fair point. The way my workflow works is, when a user finishes with foo, foo calls a scheduler function which schedules the function after foo in the list. For this, foo needs to be aware of its own index in the list. I don't wish to hard code numbers, which is why I'm trying to retrieve the index of foo.

Comment: You could pass around an `Iterator` (in a thread safe manner if needed) instead.

Comment: @Siddhartha, in that case, it sounds like you should be using a different data structure than a `List` -- perhaps you should be writing a structure specifically for a chain of functions that doesn't require indexing at all.

Comment: @Siddhartha, if you are _always_ going to to schedule the next operation to be run after executing the consumer, then this should be handled outside of the consumer, to avoid repeating it in each consumer. If not always, then you can implement it as a callback to let the consumer decide, or change your consumer to something with a return value that lets the calling code handle it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no guarantee from the language that the instance resulting from evaluating the same method (or constructor) reference or the same lambda expression will always be the same.

Your only option (with regards to aforementioned method references) is to capture the reference to the object the first time around and reuse it

```
private final Consumer<String> barConsumer = this::bar;
private final Consumer<String> fooConsumer = this::foo;
private final List<Consumer<String>> activities = ImmutableList.of(barConsumer, fooConsumer);

public void print() {
    System.out.println(activities.indexOf(fooConsumer);
}
```

<sub>Though it's still unclear why you'd want this.</sub>

Comment: I see what you're saying. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: More precisely: multiple evaluations of the "same" lambda expression or method reference is not guaranteed to result in the same (according to ==) object.